# Oracle error ORA-00942, rails 3 environment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, oracle

Hoping someone will have some insight into this issue. There are a lot of posts regarding this error, and I have read all of them.

Running a Rails 3 app on an Oracle 11 db. Rails attempts to create a new object, and it blows up (500) and I get back ORA 00942, table or view does not exist. Table does exist. Sequence exists and I can both write to the table and pull sequence numbers using SQL Developer and the same credentials that are used to run the rails app. Permissions look fine. I have looked at the rails model associations, and tracked down all of the tables and sequences of those objects as well.

One of the columns in the table is a CLOB column, and it seems like there can be issues with that datatype. But those seem to come from Java environments.

I have schema owner credentials, is there a log I could check to see the exact sql statement that is causing the error? Any sort of lower level logging I could turn on to get more insight into what is going on?

Comment: Is it perhaps as simple as case sensitivity of table name ? If an ora table is named all caps, you can either not use speech marks, or use them but put the table name in all caps in the query. If a table name is not all caps, your query must use speech marks and replicate the case of the table exactly

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a missing grant on a sequence. Very frustrating that Oracle reports this as 00942.

If you get this problem, and the table is present, look carefully at the grants that have been made to both the table and the sequence. You can do this with the following syntax in SQL Developer:

select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where table_name = name_of_thing_you_want

Yes, sequences also fall under the table_name heading.

To create a grant:

grant select ON the_name_of_the_object TO name_of_the_user

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: One last note, if you encounter this is a rails environment, keep in mind, that you need to look at not just the object you are trying to create, but all objects down stream that are being created or touched during object creation or through callbacks. Look at your model associations.